# Angular Firestore Database (Cloud firestore) how to update existing document data

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I get a document on the following way

The imports:

```
  import { Firestore, collectionData, collection, DocumentData } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
```

A class variables:

```
myDocData$: Observable<DocumentData[]>;
firestore: Firestore = inject(Firestore);
```

The code:

```
  const itemCollection = collection(this.firestore, 'mydocdata');
  this.myDocData$ = collectionData(itemCollection);
  this.myDocData$.subscribe(data =>{
    ...
  });
```

My question is how can I update my document data?
(so I would like to update my document data in the Firestore)

How can I use setDoc()? Could you please provide an example?
Or could you please provide me, where can I found that on the [official website](https://github.com/angular/angularfire)?

The document have two fields a location and the data, both type are string.

The document in cloud firestore:
[image]

Comment: are you referring to updating data on firestore? If so, not sure if you are looking for a PUT/POST API. If possible, please elaborate your questions with additional details so that we can assist. Appreciate it.

Comment: yes, I would like to update the firestore document with my changes.